# django modelform css class for select

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I am trying to add in a class with the name of autocomplete into one of my select.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['user']

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['specie'].queryset = Specie.objects.all(attrs={'class':'autocomplete'})
```

Based on the code above I get `all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the existing code as shown below and try again.

```
self.fields['specie'].queryset = Specie.objects.all()
self.fields['specie'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'autocomplete'
```

Explanation: the first line sets the `queryset` for the field, i.e. values to choose from. The right hand side filters all objects of `Specie`. A HTML/CSS attribute has no relevance here.
The second line tells the widget used to render the field to use a specific CSS class.

Comment: And you cant forget changing the overwriting of the method `__init__`. There is no user argument!